# Building Spreadsheet to Scrape

Tags: excel, vba

From what I have pulled together, I am trying to write in VBA to pull up AirBnB from Internet Explorer. I want to type in: 1. a location 2. Date Range. After this I ewould like it to display the first 4 onto my spreadsheet.

I've tried following Youtube videos after I miserably failed writing on my own.

```
Sub pulldata()

Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate "https://www.airbnb.com/s/homes?adults=1&children=0&checkin=&checkout=&source=mc_search_bar"

Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set doc = IE.document

doc.getElementById ("Koan-via-SearchHeader_input"), Value = ""
```

I would like to press a button on my spreadsheet and it search AirBnB for "New York, Downtown, X Date to Y Date. Then have it paste the top four options on my spreadsheet with the Name & Price.

Answer (score 0):

Your last line should be: `Set elem = doc.getElementById ("Koan-via-SearchHeader__input")`. Note that you are missing an underscore in the id. Declare `elem` as an `Object`.